# which services are provided by the operating system to execute the C program

Tags: c, operating-system

Regarding the execution of the c program, i am aware that compiler converts the code into machine language and then it is executed.But i would like to know which services are provided by the operating system to accomplish that. say iam using fopen function, please explain me how the operating system handles it, ie. reading the file from hard disk to loading into memory...etc . for all those operations,which system calls are internally called?how the explicit functions like fopen,printf are converted into system calls? 
If it is possible to view the internal system calls in context to c programming,please let me know the path to be followed to see them?

Comment: functions (rather, function **calls**) are not converted into system calls. functions are just functions and function calls usually translated to normal `CALL` instructions. The called low-level functions, in turn, may be implemented in assembly, whereby the programmer who wrote e. g. `fopen()` will have used a system call to have the operating system hand him back an open file handle, etc.

Comment: Typically the `fopen` function will be in a library that's either bundled with the compiler or designed to work with a particular compiler; and that function will ultimately call an operating system function (e.g. `CreateFile` in Windows) . The operating system does everything from that point onwards.

Comment: will you please explain me in detail with reference to above code?

Comment: I think the biggest obstacle to giving a definitive answer to your question is the lack of a generally agreed upon definition of what an operating system is.  Some folks will argue that the C standard library is part of the operating system, others will disagree.  For you matter, it will probably be useful to define the operating system narrowly as the *operating system kernel*.

Comment: i opened the file printf.h and iam finding only declarations.Where to find its complete definition and how do i came to know which system calls it is using?

Comment: For Windows the system call for opening a file is [`NtCreateFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb432380%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). If `printf` is writing to a console window, the system call depends on the version of Windows. Prior to Windows 8 it uses the LPC system call `NtRequestWaitReplyPort` to call `SrvWriteConsole` in conhost.exe. Windows 8 instead calls `NtWriteFile` since it has a console kernel device.

Comment: Every decent compiler includes the source code for the C runtime library it uses.  In which you'll find the underlying operating system calls that are used to implement a function like fopen().  Have a look-see.

Comment: It would be great if you tell me how to do it with little bit explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Languages typically have their own APIs as part of their run-time support (e.g. `fopen()` in C's standard library). These are part of the language and not strictly part of the OS itself.

The language's run-time uses the OS's lower level APIs. For example, `fopen()` might use the kernel API's `open()` function (Linux); but then it might be a `createfile()` function in a DLL and not something in the kernel at all (Windows). In some cases, it's nothing like that and more like a message sent to a different process (common for micro-kernels).

Regardless of where it ends up (and how), it probably finds its way to some sort of "virtual file system" layer, and depending on whether it's in the VFS's caches it may or may not get forwarded from there to code responsible for handling a file system, which may or may not forward it to some sort of storage device driver (e.g. a USB flash device driver), which in turn might forward it to another device driver (e.g. a USB controller driver).

Mostly, it can be very different for different OSs, so there is no single answer that's correct for all of them.